# Apply IntVar() to focused Entry() tkinter

Tags: tkinter, python-2.x

I have a tkinter application which has 2 entry boxes and buttons with numbers 0-9. I wish to be able to enter an `IntVar()` using the buttons but into the focused `Entry()`. At the minute I can apply the button presses to enter `IntVar()` into the first `Entry()` box but I cannot figure out, or find online, how to only enter the `IntVar()` into the focused `Entry()` box.

```
import sys
from tkinter import Tk, Text, BOTH, W, N, E, S, IntVar
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button, Label, Style, Entry

expression = ''

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.name = 'Application'
        self.master.title(self.name)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        cancel_btn_style = Style()
        cancel_btn_style.configure('CNL.TButton', background='red')
        cancel_btn_style = Style()
        cancel_btn_style.configure('LGN.TButton', background='green')

        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)

        self.user_number_var = IntVar()

        self.main_label = Label(self, text=self.name)
        self.main_label.grid(sticky=W, pady=4, padx=5)

        self.entry_label = Label(self, text='User Number / PIN')
        self.entry_label.grid(
            row=1, column=0, columnspan=1,
            rowspan=1, padx=5, sticky=E+W+S+N
        )

        vcmd = (self.register(self.__vcmd), '%P')

        self.user_number_entry = Entry(
            self, validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd, 
            textvariable=self.user_number_var
        )
        self.user_number_entry.grid(
            row=1, column=1, columnspan=1, 
            rowspan=1, sticky=N+S+E+W, pady=4
        )

        self.pin_number_entry = Entry(self, validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd, show='*')
        self.pin_number_entry.grid(
            row=1, column=2, columnspan=1, 
            rowspan=1, sticky=N+S+E+W, pady=4
        )

        self.btn_1 = Button(self, text='1', command=lambda: self.press(1))
        self.btn_1.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)

        self.btn_2 = Button(self, text='2', command=lambda: self.press(2))
        self.btn_2.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)

        self.btn_3 = Button(self, text='3', command=lambda: self.press(3))
        self.btn_3.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)

        self.btn_4 = Button(self, text='4', command=lambda: self.press(4))
        self.btn_4.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)

        self.btn_5 = Button(self, text='5', command=lambda: self.press(5))
        self.btn_5.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)

        self.btn_6 = Button(self, text='6', command=lambda: self.press(6))
        self.btn_6.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)

        self.btn_7 = Button(self, text='7', command=lambda: self.press(7))
        self.btn_7.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)

        self.btn_8 = Button(self, text='8', command=lambda: self.press(8))
        self.btn_8.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)

        self.btn_9 = Button(self, text='9', command=lambda: self.press(9))
        self.btn_9.grid(row=4, column=2, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)

        self.cancel_btn = Button(self, text='Cancel / Close', command=sys.exit, style='CNL.TButton')
        self.cancel_btn.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)

        self.btn_0 = Button(self, text='0', command=lambda: self.press(0))
        self.btn_0.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)

        self.login_btn = Button(self, text='Log In', style='LGN.TButton')
        self.login_btn.grid(row=5, column=2, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)

    def press(self, num):
        # point out the global expression variable
        global expression

        # concatenation of string
        expression = expression + str(num)

        # update the expression by using set method
        self.user_number_var.set(expression)

    def __vcmd(self, P, S):
        print('__vcmd')

def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('540x640')
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I need the buttons to enter digits into `self.user_number_entry` or `self.pin_number_entry` depending on which one has focus.

Comment: Firstly your the first (rude) person to say that short code block is anywhere near too long/much, so please calm down in your tone! I don't appreciate it, your are not high and mighty because you have lot's of rep! Its people such as yourself that this community  renowned for being unfriendly. Now it's my understanding that my code uses `self.user_number_var = IntVar()` to initialise a integer variable and use said `IntVar()` being assigned to the name of `self.user_number_var` which sets the text in the `self.user_number_entry`.

Comment: I'm sorry if you took offense. I tried to ask as politely as I could (_"please reduce..."_).  Thanks for the clarification. If I understand your comment correct, when you wrote "enter an IntVar", you actually mean "assign an IntVar to an entry". Is that correct? I still don't understand what this has to do with focus, though. Why do you only want the variable associated with the focused widget, rather than one for each widget?

Comment: Maybe I also took your comment to heart (I'm just sick of people being rude on here,, it makes people not want to be here) anyway lets move forward. In my mind we *enter* into an `Entry()` not assign to one. Anyway, I am proficient with Gtk class-based GUI's and trying to learn more complex tkinter GUI's and so I am at that stage where things just don't quite make sense yet. Basically I don't have to do this the way I have established, I just want to be able to use the numbered buttons to enter digits into the `Entry()` that has focus at any given moment, .....[cont]

Comment: So if I click on `self.user_number_entry` then clicking on the buttons will enter that digit into `self.user_number_entry` and then when I have entered the user number and click on `self.pin_number_entry` clicking on the buttons will enter the digit into `self.pin_number_entry`. It's at the point where I have tried so many variations that I have become confused and can't keep track of what I have tried already, I have tried Chuck G's answer but it seems not to work.

Comment: Yes, a user enters data into an entry field. However, you don't "enter" a IntVar which is where my confusion was.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187593/discussion-between-jack-herer-and-bryan-oakley).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correct, all you're really asking is how the button should know where to insert the text. I don't think the use of `IntVar` really has anything to do with it, that's an [xy problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). You can use `IntVar`s if you wish, but they have no relationship with this problem.

Tkinter provides a command to get the currently focused widget -- `focus_get`. When you click a button, you can insert the text to the end of that widget. You don't need to use an `IntVar`.

*However*, you're using ttk buttons which steal the focus. A bad design decision on the part of the ttk developers, but that's beside the point. The simplest solution is to keep track of which entry widget last had focus. You can then append the digit directly in the entry widget.

Start by adding a binding on each entry widget, to remember itself when it gets focus. Do this in the same method that creates the entries, sometime after the entries have been created:

```
self.user_number_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", self._remember_focus)
self.pin_number_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", self._remember_focus)
```

Next, we need to define the `_remember_focus` method to remember which widget last had the focus:

```
def _remember_focus(self, event):
    self._current_entry = event.widget
```

Finally, we need to modify the `press` command to append the number directly into the entry widget. In this example I also reset the focus to the entry widget. I'm not sure if you want that or not.

```
def press(self, num):
    self._current_entry.insert("end", str(num))
    self._current_entry.focus_set()
```

---

Note: you have other bugs in your code that will prevent this from working. Specifically, you have bugs in your entry validation code. This is why we ask for a [mcve] (with a focus on *minimum*), since it makes it hard for us to focus just on the question being asked. The other code clouds the issue.

A short fix so that you know this solution is working is to temporarily turn off your input validation.

Also, this solution assumes that you've clicked into one of the entries before you click a button. You can work around that by calling `self.user_number_entry.focus_set()` in your `__init__`, which will force the input focus to start at that entry widget.

Comment: Perfect! Thankyou, I haven't heard of an xy problem before today and it couldn't be more spot on, Because I'm new to tkinter coming from Gtk a lot of tkinter concepts seem strange, I'm still at the early discovery stage. Your answer has relieved my current question and for that I am grateful, whats strange is that the input validation worked fine when I was only doing `self.user_number_var.set(expression)`, but thats another issue for me to try solve, cheers, and apologies for any misunderstandings previously.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a bind to the `"<FocusIn>"` event to check which of the entries is focused and `insert` your value:

```
....

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ....
    self.user_number_var = IntVar()
    self.pin_number_var = IntVar()
    self.user_number_entry = Entry(
        self, validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd, 
        textvariable=self.user_number_var
    )
    self.user_number_entry.grid(
        row=1, column=1, columnspan=1, 
        rowspan=1, sticky=N+S+E+W, pady=4
    )
    self.user_number_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", self.remember_focus)

    self.pin_number_entry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.pin_number_var, validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd, show='*')
    self.pin_number_entry.grid(
        row=1, column=2, columnspan=1, 
        rowspan=1, sticky=N+S+E+W, pady=4
    )
    self.pin_number_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", self.remember_focus)
    ....

def remember_focus(self,event):
    global focused_entry
    focused_entry = event.widget    

def press(self, num):
    focused_entry.insert('end',str(num))
```

Another solution if you will insist on using `IntVar()` is to `bind` individual functions to each `entry`, then set a `global variable` to the IntVar() in focus, which allows you to then input your expression to the in focus entry's `IntVar()` :

```
...
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user_number_var = IntVar()
    self.pin_number_var = IntVar()

    self.main_label = Label(self, text=self.name)
    self.main_label.grid(sticky=W, pady=4, padx=5)

    self.entry_label = Label(self, text='User Number / PIN')
    self.entry_label.grid(
        row=1, column=0, columnspan=1,
        rowspan=1, padx=5, sticky=E+W+S+N
    )

    self.user_number_entry = Entry(
        self, validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd, 
        textvariable=self.user_number_var
    )
    self.user_number_entry.grid(
        row=1, column=1, columnspan=1, 
        rowspan=1, sticky=N+S+E+W, pady=4
    )
    self.user_number_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", self.set_user_number_int_var)

    self.pin_number_entry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.pin_number_var, validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd, show='*')
    self.pin_number_entry.grid(
        row=1, column=2, columnspan=1, 
        rowspan=1, sticky=N+S+E+W, pady=4
    )
    self.pin_number_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", self.set_pin_number_int_var)
...

def set_user_number_int_var(self,event):
    global set_int_var
    set_int_var = self.user_number_var

def set_pin_number_int_var(self,event):
    global set_int_var
    set_int_var = self.pin_number_var        


def press(self, num):
    # point out the global expression variable
    global expression,set_int_var

    # concatenation of string
    expression = expression + str(num)
    set_int_var.set(expression)
```

One draw back: the concatenation:

```
 expression = expression + str(num)
```

This will carry over anything already in `expression` should the user change the focus of the entry, and that I guess is not a desired behavior.

Comment: I was playing around with the bind function but could not get it to work as expected so thought maybe it was the wrong approach. I will test your example as soon as I'm at my computer. Much appreciated.

Comment: @BryanOakley, instead of just saying people are wrong, why not actually provide some help? You have spent time commenting about wrong i am and how wrong Chuck G is but you don't actually say anything helpful! How would one "ask it for the widget that currently has focus"? I tried something like that in amongst the several variations I tried in the process and `get_focus()` and `set_focus()` wouldn't work, I have seen you answering many questions on tkinter so you certainly would be able to help but instead you offer nothing useful,I suggest you join https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: My apologies. I didn't realize you were using ttk buttons which steal the focus. It's a very annoying design decision on the part of the ttk developers. I've removed my earlier comment.

Comment: @Chuck G thanks for the effort but your solution simply did not work.